# Why the space of skew-symmetric tensors $\Lambda^{n}V$ is a one dimensional if $dim(V)=n$

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, tensors

While reading Liviu Nicolaescu  Lectures on the geometry of manifolds, I came accross the notion of "determinant line":

**Definition:** Lev $V$ be an n-dimensional R-vector space. The one dimensional vector space $\Lambda^{n}V$ is called the **determinant line**. Here, $\Lambda^{n}V$ is a space of skew-symmetric (a.k.a. antisymmetric) tensors.

My question is why $\Lambda^{n}V$ is a one-dimensional vector space? I think that this has something to do with the fact that the degrees of the tensors in that spaces is equal to the dimension of $V$, i.e. $n=dim V$. But I cann't figure this one out. Any guidance would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a basis $e_i$ of the vector space $V$, one can show that $Λ^kV$ has a basis composed of

$$e_{i_1}\wedge e_{i_2}\wedge\dots\wedge e_{i_k}\text{ where }1\le i_1<i_2<\dots<i_k\le n,$$

so $\dim Λ^kV=\binom nk$. Thus $Λ^nV$ has exactly one basis element and so dimension $1$.

Comment: Indeed, if $v_1, \dotsc, v_n \in V$, then
$$
 v_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge v_n = \det(v_{ij}) e_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge e_n,
$$
where for each $j$,
$$
 v_j = \sum_{i} v_{ij} e_i.
$$